# "invalid escape sequence" error when using genie in julia

Tags: julia

I'm studying Genie by the example in https://github.com/essenciary/Genie.jl
When I went to the step of connecting SearchLight to DB, as following:

```
julia> SearchLight.Configuration.load_db_connection() |> 
SearchLight.Database.connect!
```

it kept having the following problem:

```
ERROR: Base.Meta.ParseError("invalid escape sequence")

Stacktrace:
 [1] #parse#1(::Bool, ::Bool, ::Bool, ::Function, ::String, ::Int64) at .\meta.jl:129 

 [2] #parse at .\none:0 [inlined]

 [3] #parse#4(::Bool, ::Bool, ::Function, ::String) at .\meta.jl:164

 [4] parse at .\meta.jl:164 [inlined]

 [5] setup_adapter(::String) at C:\Users\19652\.julia\packages\SearchLight\JA5Zc\src\Database.jl:10

 [6] setup_adapter() at C:\Users\19652\.julia\packages\SearchLight\JA5Zc\src\Database.jl:9

 [7] connect!(::Dict{String,Any}) at C:\Users\19652\.julia\packages\SearchLight\JA5Zc\src\Database.jl:53

 [8] top-level scope at none:0
```

Does anyone know how to fix it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I would try it in Linux (inside of VirtualBox or something) or to find path like 'C:\Users\19652\...' and convert it to 'C:/Users/19652/...'